# Three.js camera rotation issue

Tags: coffeescript, three.js, webgl

I want to rotate the camera around the x-axis on the y-z plane while looking at the `(0, 0, 0)` point. It turns out the `lookAt` function behaves weird. When after rotating 180°, the geometry jump to another side unexpectedly. Could you please explain why this happens, and how to avoid it?

You can see the live demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ysmood/dryEa/

```
class Stage
    constructor: ->
        window.requestAnimationFrame = 
            window.requestAnimationFrame or
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame or
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame

        @init_scene()
        @make_meshes()

    init_scene: ->
        @scene = new THREE.Scene

        # Renderer
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        @renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: document.querySelector('.scene')
        })
        @renderer.setSize(width, height)

        # Camera
        @camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            45,                 # fov
            width / height,     # aspect
            1,                  # near
            1000                # far
        )
        @scene.add(@camera)

    make_meshes: ->
        size = 20
        num = 1

        geo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, size, size)
        material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material)
        mesh.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2

        @scene.add(mesh)

    draw: =>
        angle = Date.now() * 0.001
        radius = 100

        @camera.position.set(
            0,
            radius * Math.cos(angle),
            radius * Math.sin(angle)
        )
        @camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3())

        @renderer.render(@scene, @camera)
        requestAnimationFrame(@draw)

stage = new Stage
stage.draw()
```

Comment: You are probably hitting Gimbal Lock issues (you can research that on the net). Solution is to use Quaternion rotations instead (also researchable). Note that latest Three.js, r59 now uses quaternions by default, and there are new rotation methods available in Object3D which may help (rotateX(), rotateAroundAxis() and friends).

Comment: Are you sure this is a Gimbal Lock issue? The problem is I don't know the mechanism of the `lookAt` function. And why not the team don't use Quaternion inside the `lookAt` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rotating the camera around the X-axis in the Y-Z plane. When the camera passes over the "north" and "south" poles, it flips so as to stay right-side-up. The camera's up-vector is `(0, 1, 0)` by default.

Set the camera x-position to 100 so, and its behavior will appear correct to you. Add some axes to your demo for a frame of reference.

This is not a fault of the library. Have a look at the `Camera.lookAt()` source code.

If you want to set the camera orientation via its quaternion instead, you can do that.

three.js r.59

Comment: I read the source code. Thanks, it helps. The docs of three.js misled my thought.

Comment: I have given an offset to the x position, but the same problem appears http://jsfiddle.net/ysmood/dryEa/

Comment: To help you understand what is happening, set the camera offset to 200, then 50, then 20. Everything is working as it should -- the camera is avoiding being rotated upside-down. If you don't care if the camera is upside-down, then use `TrackballControls` to control your camera. http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html